# Proving coordinate vector of a set is equal to coordinate vector of a linear transformation set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Suppose I have two vectorspace, $V$ and $W$, and $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation.

We define $S = \{v_1 .... v_k\} \subset V$, and $T(S) = \{T(v_i) \mid v_i \in S\} \subset W$.

Now we assume $S$ is an ordered basis of $V$ (where $i$th element is $v_i$) and $T(S)$ is an ordered basis of $W$ ($i$th element is $T(v_i)$).

Now let $v$ be a vector in $V$.

How can I prove that the coordinate vector $v$ with respect to $S$ is equal to the coordinate vector $T(v)$ with respect to $T(S)$?

Or in other words: $[v]_S$ = $[T(v)]_{T(S)}$

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to a straightforward application of definitions.

Let $x$ be the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $S$. When we say that $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$ is the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $S$ (i.e. $x = [v]_S$), we mean that the entries of $x$ are such that
$$
v = x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n.
$$
By the linearity of $T$, it follows that
$$
T(v) = T(x_1 v_1 + \cdots + x_n v_n) = x_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + x_n T(v_n).
$$
By the definition of a coordinate vector, this tells us that
$$
x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) = [T(v)]_{T(S)}.
$$
In other words, we indeed have $[v]_S = [T(v)]_{T(S)}.$

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense now. Also thanks for prettifying my question.